# Excel/iReport date type

Tags: excel, date, jasper-reports, report

I make a report in *iReport* with an Excel file. In the Excel file I use these time types:

```
h:mm
yyyy.mm.dd  h:mm
```

When I start a new report I am getting this message:

```
Error filling print... Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
```

How can I solve this problem?

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0d91d166-e8ce-41e5-84a3-281818349b26">
<field name="Related To" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TC Total Time" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TC Start" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TC End" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Assigned To" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TC Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TC Description" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Support? " class="java.lang.String"/>  
<field name="Support Time" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader> <detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file and the *Java* code (if you have) to reproduce the issue

Comment: Your template is empty. Are you sure that you post right one?

Comment: excel stores dates as a Numeric (a MS version of EPOCH) you will need to convert it in excel to text or in Jasper to text. if you do it in Jasper you are going to have to do some math and conversion to get it back into a date.